# React - componentWillReceiveProps alternative

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I use React with NextJS.

I have a component which is basically a table which gives some summary.
Based on some UI selection, this component is expected to show appropriate summary.

The below code works perfectly fine.

```
class Summary extends Component{

    state = {
        total: 0,
        pass: 0,
        fail: 0,
        passp: 0,
        failp: 0
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(props){
        let total = props.results.length;
        let pass  = props.results.filter(r => r.status == 'pass').length;
        let fail  = total - pass;
        let passp = (pass/(total || 1) *100).toFixed(2);
        let failp = (fail/(total || 1) *100).toFixed(2);
        this.setState({total, pass, fail, passp, failp});
    }

    render() {
        return(
          <Table color="teal" >
                <Table.Header>
                  <Table.Row textAlign="center">
                    <Table.HeaderCell>TOTAL</Table.HeaderCell>
                    <Table.HeaderCell>PASS</Table.HeaderCell>
                    <Table.HeaderCell>FAIL</Table.HeaderCell>
                    <Table.HeaderCell>PASS %</Table.HeaderCell>
                    <Table.HeaderCell>FAIL %</Table.HeaderCell>                                 
                  </Table.Row>
                </Table.Header>
                <Table.Body>
                  <Table.Row textAlign="center">
                    <Table.Cell>{this.state.total}</Table.Cell>
                    <Table.Cell >{this.state.pass}</Table.Cell>
                    <Table.Cell >{this.state.fail}</Table.Cell>                                     
                    <Table.Cell >{this.state.passp}</Table.Cell>
                    <Table.Cell >{this.state.failp}</Table.Cell>                                      
                  </Table.Row>
                </Table.Body>
           </Table>             
        );
    }
}
```

Looks like `componentWillReceiveProps` will be deprecated. I tried other options like `shouldComponentUpdate` etc..they all lead to infinite loop. What is best approach to update the state from the props to re-render this component?

Comment: componentWillReceiveProps will be deprecated ? Are you using React17?there is no code in above script  which cause infinite loop

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN as i said, it would be deprecated. Also this component works just fine. I am looking for alternative

Comment: @DenisTsoi  getDerivedStateFromProps is static. i can not call `setState`

Comment: you can view the answer below to view how to set state with `getDerivedState` -

Comment: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html#updating-state-based-on-props

Answer (score 48, accepted):

From react [blog](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html), 16.3 introduced deprecation notices for `componentWillRecieveProps`.

As a workaround, you would use the method

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState)
```

therefore

```
componentWillReceiveProps(props){
    let total = props.results.length;
    let pass  = props.results.filter(r => r.status == 'pass').length;
    let fail  = total - pass;
    let passp = (pass/(total || 1) *100).toFixed(2);
    let failp = (fail/(total || 1) *100).toFixed(2);
    this.setState({total, pass, fail, passp, failp});
}
```

becomes

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
  if (nextProps.total !== prevState.total) {
    return ({ total: nextProps.total }) // <- this is setState equivalent
  }
  return null
}
```

Comment: The recommendation from React is to use componentDidUpdate isntead of getDerivedStateFromProps, If you need to perform a side effect (for example, data fetching or an animation) in response to a change in props. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops, https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html#fetching-external-data-when-props-change

Comment: @user1912383 It's not necessary to use componentDidUpdate, it depends on a case to case, react recommend getDerivedStateFromProps alternative also: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#alternative-1-reset-uncontrolled-component-with-an-id-prop

Comment: and add:
else return null

Comment: Yes forgetting the else will cause some errors

Comment: how to setState inside getDerivedStateFromProps method if it is async

Comment: @Kingalione how will forgetting the else cause errors?