# React Component - reload data within multiple times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Imagine a simple React component with `<select>` element that allows to choose a city based on country. For example

```
<MyCitySelectComponent
  country={ 'France' }
  city={ 'Paris' }
  onChange={ someFunction }
/>
```

- When mounted, it should load list of available Cities (based on Country) and render `<select>`.
- When city property is changed - it should modify `<select>` input value and trigger onChange event.
- When country property is changed (from parent component) - it should reload list of available cities from a remote server and trigger the same onChange event.

I managed to implement first two, here is simplified code:

---

```
class MyCitySelectComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(...props);

        this.state = {
            cities: null,
            city: props.city,
            country: props.country
        };
    }

    onCityChange( e ) {
        this.setState({
            city: e.target.value
        });

        this.props.onChange( e.target.value );
    }

    loadCities() {
        fetch({
            path: '/get/cities?country=' + this.state.country,
        }).then( cities => {
            this.setState({
                cities: cities
            });
        });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.loadCities();
    }

    render() {
        if ( !this.state.cities ) {
            // not loaded yet
            return null;
        }

        return (
            <select>
                { this.state.cities.map( ( name, index ) =>
                    <option
                        value={ name }
                        onChange={ this.onCityChange }
                        selected={ name === this.state.city }
                    />
                ) }
            </select>
        )
    }
}
```

But I'm having trouble reloading cities when country is changed dynamically from parent component. I tried using `shouldComponentUpdate`, but all I get is infinite loops.

Is there any pattern for such type of component?

Thank you.

Comment: This might be what you want [getDerivedStateFromProps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50692160/react-componentwillreceiveprops-alternative)

Answer (score 1):

Fetching new data based on prop changes should be handled in `componentDidUpdate` or `getDerivedStateFromProps`. Have a look at the docs for an example: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html#fetching-external-data-when-props-change

Note that `componentWillReceiveProps` is deprecated!