# Sending a post request to jsonplaceholder fails in React Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, http-post, jsonplaceholder

I made a simple React Redux application that fetches a list of posts from [jsonplaceholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts) and within it is a form that allows users to send a POST request. When I send a post request according to Redux DevTools extension it is added successfully marked as post number 101. Here is its snapshot

[image]

but the problem is after clicking the submit button 3 times it shows up on the screen.

[image]

The first two clicks show neither the title nor its body but it starts showing up on the third click.
This is `Posts.jsx` file and here is how I used `componentDidUpdate` to update the component after post request.

```
class Posts extends Component {
    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.fetchPosts();
    }

    componentDidUpdate(nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.newPost) {
            this.props.posts.unshift(nextProps.newPost);
        }
    }
    
    renderPosts(){ // cutted for brevity  }

    render() {
        return (
            {this.renderPosts()}
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        posts: state.posts.items,
        newPost: state.posts.item,
    }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchPosts })(Posts);
```

[Here is its GitHub link repository](https://github.com/abasirpayenda/ab-basir).
The only error I am getting is the below error.

```
index.js:1 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
```

I don't believe this has anything to do with rendering the new post, but I already specified a "key" while looping through components.

What I am doing wrong during the course of this post request? Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong lifeCycle method. in order to get the `nexProps` you have to use `componentWillReceiveProps` instead of `componentDidUpdate`.

componentDidUpdate will give you the previous Props and previous State.

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.newPost) {
      this.props.posts.unshift(nextProps.newPost);
    }
  }
```

The above snippet should work.

But this method is deprecated. react introduced an alternative (kind of) of this. which is called `getDerivedStateFromProps`. The problem is it is a static method and you can't access previous props (this.props) inside this method.

If you need it you did something wrong as it is an anti-pattern.

Comment: Yes thank you for commenting. Isn't it unsafe now?  In React documentation it is said that this life cycle is unsafe and should be avoided at all cost.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#updating

Comment: yes, It is deprecated. you can try `static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState)`

for details check it out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50692160/react-componentwillreceiveprops-alternative

Comment: I am confused React recommends `componentDidUpdate` instead of `getDerivedStateFromProps`. 
And please update your answer.

Comment: Thank you for updating the answer. The problem is I can't access `this` within this static method. Any solution? How I update the component after POST request?